# Dumping LLVMModule with Value Names using the C-API

Tags: c, rust, llvm, llvm-ir

I am currently writing my own compiler using Rust and LLVM and therefore, the LLVM-C-API.

For Debugging purposes, the LLVM-C-API provides a Function called [LLVMDumpModule()](https://llvm.org/doxygen/group__LLVMCCoreModule.html#ga31c87315ba3f595d6786c47a50d9f8e7).
Sadly, this seems to completely discard any previously provided value names, making debugging much harder than it needs to be. In the C++ API, this can be toggled via a parameter to the dumpModule Function, but this is not the case for the C-API.

Minimal Example (in Rust, using llvm-sys crate)

```
extern crate llvm_sys as llvm;
fn main() {
let ctx = LLVMContextCreate();
let mod =LLVMModuleCreateWithNameInContext(c_str("main_ctx"), ctx);
LLVMAddFunction(
        mod,
        c_str("my_func"),
        <my func type>, <params> //Sghortened for brevity
    );
LLVMDumpModule(mod);
```

What this should dump, is the following:

```
define i64 @my_func(<some args>)
```

What it actually dumps:

```
define i64 @1(<some args>)
```

This is the same for all LLVM-IR Instructions, all my provided names for values are just not dumped. Any advice on how to enable this using the LLVM-C-API?

Comment: I can't recall [any such option?](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Module.html#acf2ab2f5fc12e938c8397375d29a580f) Anyway, why don'y you just contribute a small change to llvm-c?

Comment: I am actualy more confused now. I am 100% sure I remember a option to print a module with the value names in cpp but I can not find it anymore. 
So, if there is no way to print the Module with the value names, why am I able to set the value names in the first place? What are they used for?

Comment: When I set names by passing them to e.g. BinaryOperator::Create(), the names are used as you expect (and I agree with you, naming simplifies work). You might also consider looking at whether the names arrive in the BinaryOperator class after being passed through the rust crate and llvm-c.

Comment: I just figured out what the problem was. I was creating the names as Rust CStrings, that were dropped as soon as the scope changed. Therefore, all my value name strings were just empty. So, this wasn't a LLVM specific issue at all, its just me not being careful with Rust lifetimes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out what the problem was. I was creating the names as Rust CStrings, that were dropped as soon as the scope changed. Therefore, all my value name strings were just empty. So, this wasn't a LLVM specific issue at all, its just me not being careful with Rust lifetimes.